# (Flutter) How to move a textbox that is blocked by the keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, textbox, scrollable

I'm trying to make a comment section that has textbox inside bottom sheet. I've been trying to us viewInsets padding but is still not work and i have no idea whats wrong with my code. So please help

this is my bottomSheet [Bottom Sheet](https://imgur.com/a/UQQlpjM) and this is the problem what i faced [Bottom Sheet Problem](https://imgur.com/a/JDEQbv6)

this is my code :

main

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                        useRootNavigator: true,
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                            top: Radius.circular(16),
                          ),
                        ),
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return Wrap(
                            children: [
                              CustomBottomSheetBuilder(
                                tinggi: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                isi: const [
                                  CommentContent(),
                                ],
                                header: true,
                                judul: 'Comments',
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        });
```

CustomBottomSheetBuilder

```
Container(
      height: widget.tinggi - kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: MyColor.white,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          widget.header == true
              ? Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      bottom: BorderSide(
                        width: .5,
                        color: MyColor.neutralLow,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  height: 64,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          widget.judul == null ? '' : widget.judul!,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: MyColor.neutralHigh,
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextActionButton(
                          teks: 'Cancel',
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : const SizedBox(
                  height: 48,
                ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: ListView(
                children: widget.isi,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

CommentContent

```
ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                final Comment comments = commentList[index];
                return Card(
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(3),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 12,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                comments.image,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    comments.name,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    comments.day,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      color: MyColor.neutralMediumLow,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Spacer(),
                            CustomPopupMenuButton(
                                itemBuilder: (context) => [
                                      PopupMenuItem(
                                        value: 1,
                                        // row has two child icon and text.
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "Delete Comment",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: MyColor.danger,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                onSelected: (value) {
                                  if (value == 1) {}
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                          child: Text(comments.comment),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
              itemCount: commentList.length,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
              child: TextBox(
                textEditingController: commentController,
                hintText: 'Type what are you thinking here ...',
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. I have not tested it yet. I'm pretty sure you need to add this to showModalBottomSheet() to make the bottom sheet come up along with the keyboard

```
isScrollControlled: true
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried but bottomsheet height becomes full screen. I just want the bottomsheet height to remain the default height